# How do I make a Villager Trade a Spawn Egg

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a Custom Trade on a villager. I need to make him buy 8 gold nuggets and sell a Cow Spawn Egg.  basically you pay 8 nuggets for a Cow Spawner.  The ID of the Cow Spawn Egg is 92 but I don't know where to put it in the command

```
/summon Villager ~ ~2 ~ {Invulnerable:1,CustomName:Spawner_Vendor,Profession:2,Career:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:8},sell:{id:spawn_egg,Count:1}}]}}
```

Comment: have you tryed placing it in "sell:{id:[],Count:1}}]}}" place it in the []

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving players custom spawn eggs in 1.13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330808/giving-players-custom-spawn-eggs-in-1-13)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Damage:` value. This is the command you should run in a command block:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~2 ~ {Invulnerable:1,CustomName:Spawner_Vendor,Profession:2,Career:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:8},sell:{id:spawn_egg,Count:1,Damage:92}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about MCStacker 2? MCStacker 2 is a no-download and free command generator. Here is a 1.12 example I got from it:`/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Spawn Egg Sal",Profession:0,Career:3,CareerLevel:100,Willing:1b,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:bone",Count:10b},buyB:{id:"minecraft:rotten_flesh",Count:10b},sell:{id:"minecraft:spawn_egg",Count:1b,tag:{EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:cow"}}}}]}}`

1.13:`/summon villager ~ ~ ~ {Profession:0,Career:3,CareerLevel:100,Willing:1b,CustomName:"{\"text\":\"Spawn Egg Sal\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"bold\":true}",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:bone",Count:10b},buyB:{id:"minecraft:rotten_flesh",Count:10b},sell:{id:"minecraft:cow_spawn_egg",Count:1b}}]}}`

[MCStacker 2](https://mcstacker.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the right command `/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {PersistenceRequired:1,CustomName:Vendor,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:8},sell:{id:spawn_egg,Count:1,tag:{EntityTag:{id:cow}}},maxUses:9999999}]}}`