# Minecraft skeleton spawn egg command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ive got a command to spawn a mob, when i give the spawn egg to myself it shows that it has NBT tags but them tags dont take effect and it spawns a normal skeleton. What have i done wrong?

```
/give 1r2x skeleton_spawn_egg 1 0 {Health:10000,Glowing:1,PersistenceRequired:1,Silent:1,HandItems:[{id:bow,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:power,lvl:40}],Unbreakable:1},Count:1}],HandDropChances:[0.00F],ArmorItems:[{id:netherite_boots,Count:1},{id:netherite_leggings,Count:1},{id:netherite_chestplate,Count:1},{id:skeleton_skull,Count:1}],ArmorDropChances:[0.00F,0.00F,0.00F,0.00F],Attributes:[{Name:"generic.armor",Base:300.0F},{Name:"generic.armor_toughness",Base:10.0F},{Name:"generic.max_health",Base:1024.0F},{Name:"generic.max_health",Base:10000F}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving players custom spawn eggs in 1.13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330808/giving-players-custom-spawn-eggs-in-1-13)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the NBT in an [`EntityTag`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_Egg#Java_Edition) tag:

```
/give 1r2x skeleton_spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{Health:10000,Glowing:1,PersistenceRequired:1,Silent:1,HandItems:[{id:bow,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:power,lvl:40}],Unbreakable:1},Count:1}],HandDropChances:[0.00F],ArmorItems:[{id:netherite_boots,Count:1},{id:netherite_leggings,Count:1},{id:netherite_chestplate,Count:1},{id:skeleton_skull,Count:1}],ArmorDropChances:[0.00F,0.00F,0.00F,0.00F],Attributes:[{Name:"generic.armor",Base:300.0F},{Name:"generic.armor_toughness",Base:10.0F},{Name:"generic.max_health",Base:1024.0F},{Name:"generic.max_health",Base:10000F}]}}
```